# Contacting people who answered questions on Main site

Tags: support, communication

I read [Custom of hyphenated names in Germany](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/7913/custom-of-hyphenated-names-in-germany) which was posted about hypenated names in the Greiner family. I am very interested in some of the responses, and the information about the Greiners.

How do I contact the people who answered questions?

Comment: Welcome to G&FH:SE.  When you have enough [reputation](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to comment on answers on the site.

Answer (score 2):

Stack Exchange sites are designed around a principle that (with few exceptions) all communication between its users should be within the site and use its focused Q&A format supplemented by comments to help clarify those posts.

There is a Meta SE Q&A on [How do I contact other users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57537/how-do-i-contact-other-users) that may help you find other ways to do it, but in general we would prefer such communication to remain within questions, answers and comments.